# ioio Code LCD JHD162A cannot initialize

Tags: java, lcd, ioio

**ASKING HERE AFTER A HOMEWORK OF ABOUT 5 HRS,SO AVOID TOP SEARCH REFERENCES FROM GOOGLE**

---

i am trying to connect LCD JHD162A to ioio V1 but LCD  don't initialize, it shows a single row blackboxes,ON REFERING I MEAN THAT "**LCD is not initializing properly**" , what may be the reason ? can any one help  the **Core Code** is shown below,is there any error with code?

Connections:

---

- LCD 16x2  |   RS   |    E   |   D0   |   D1   |   D2   |   D3   |   D4   |   D5   |   D6   |    D7   |

  ---
- IOIO Board | Port 1 | Port 2 | Port 3 | Port 4 | Port 5 | Port 6 | Port 7 | Port 8 | Port 9 | Port 10 |

  ---

**all connections are OK and checked trice or more**
**info:Contrast is adjustable**

**Core Code:**

```
class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {


// Create object for assigned to output port
private DigitalOutput D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,RS,E;

// This function will do when application is startup
// Like onCreate function but use with ioio board
@Override
public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {

    // Assigned eacth object to each output port and initial state is false

    D0 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(3, false);
    D1 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(4, false);
    D2 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(5, false);
    D3 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(6, false);
    D4 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(7, false);
    D5 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(8, false);
    D6 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(9, false);
    D7 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(10, false);
    RS = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(1, false);
    E = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(2, false);



            lcd_init();
            Print("LCD is ok", 0x82);

    }


}

// This function will always running when device connect with ioio board
// It use for control ioio board
@Override
public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException { }

// Function for send high pulse to LCD
public void enable() {
    try {

        // Set e to be High
        E.write(true);

        // Send high pulse for one millisecond
        Thread.sleep(1);

        // Set back to Low
        E.write(false);
    } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
}

// Function for convert integer to boolean and send to data port on LCD
public void senddatabit(int i) {
    // Call function for convert integer to boolean
    // and set boolean logic to each port
    try {
        D0.write(check(i));
        D1.write(check(i >> 1));
        D2.write(check(i >> 2));
        D3.write(check(i >> 3));
        D4.write(check(i >> 4));
        D5.write(check(i >> 5));
        D6.write(check(i >> 6));
        D7.write(check(i >> 7));
    } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    // Call enable function
    enable();
}

// Function for convert integer value to boolean
public boolean check(int i) {

    // Create variable for convert binary to boolean
    // Use for command LCD on IOIO Board
    boolean st = false;
    i = i & 0x01;
    // If i = 0 set st = false or if i =1 set st = true
    // and return st back to main program
    if(i == 0x00)
        st = false;
    else if(i == 0x01)
        st = true;
    return st;
}

// Send command to LCD
public void lcd_command(int com) {
    try {
        // Set rs port to low
        RS.write(false);
    } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Call senddatabit for send command
    senddatabit(com);
}

// Send command to LCD
public void lcd_write(int text) {
    try {
        // Set rs port to high
        RS.write(true);
    } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Call senddatabit for send data
    senddatabit(text);
}       

// Send data to LCD
public void lcd_init() {

    // LCD 8 Bit 5x7 Dot 2 Line
    lcd_command(0x38);

    // Clear screen
    lcd_command(0x01);

    // Display on, no cursor
    lcd_command(0x0C); 


}

// Send one letters to LCD with set address
public void SendC(char c, int address) {

    // Set address
    lcd_command(address);

    // Send the letters to LCD
    lcd_write(Integer.valueOf(c));
}

// Send text string to LCD
public void Print(String str, int address) {

    // Send the letters one by one until the end
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        SendC(str.charAt(i), address);
        address++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I can't figure out how to implement it. The difference is that I'm using C instead of java. Nevertheless my code seems to be exactly yours.

Comment: hey i have solved this, i think

Comment: let we know. I 've to put it working.

Comment: let me know  what you status now?

Comment: Mine display is showing up 16 blocks on line one. That's it. I did all initializations and tried differente ones.

Comment: your circuit may be went wrong , recheck it 16 times !